# How can I create a column that orders a timestamp with a numerical value, grouped by email address

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a column that will order the timestamps 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc grouped by the email address. The end result would have a field that denotes the first timestamp from that email address with the number 1, second with 2, so on and so forth.

This would be the desired end result.

| Email | Timestamp | NEW FIELD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First@email.com | 1PM | 1 |
| First@email.com | 2PM | 2 |
| First@email.com | 3PM | 3 |
| Second@email.com | 3PM | 1 |
| Second@email.com | 4PM | 2 |

Comment: After sorting your data by A and B, then use an `IF` formula such as this in cell c2: `=IF(A2<>A1,1,C1+1)`

Comment: Yes as Isolated said, then copy the values of that column to a fourth column and delete the calculation column so values don't change when the data  reordered. Why not write that as an answer @isolated, I suggest instead of A and B call the columns by name since their addresses are not given in the OP.

Comment: @Dan Percival ,,, you may try this,,, in  C2 `=IF(A1<>A2,1,N(C1)+1)` ,,,, Function `N` used with cell C1 because C1 has Header,, and is TEXT,,,, formula will return `#VALUE` error is` N` is not been used ☺

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula that doesn't require you to sort the data in advance.  The values in the `count` column will always be correct regardless of the order of the `Email` and `Timestamp` columns.

### Formula

```
=LET(
  _arr, A2:B10,
  _seq, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_arr)/2),_arr),
  _sort, SORTBY(_seq,INDEX(_seq,,2),1,INDEX(_seq,,3),1),
  _names, INDEX(_sort,,2),
  _counters, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, MAP(UNIQUE(_names), LAMBDA(u,
        TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(_names,_names=u))))))),,","),
  FILTER(SORTBY(HSTACK(_sort,_counters),INDEX(_sort,,1),1),{0,0,0,1})
  )
```

**Counters (list in current sort order)**
[image]

**Sort by `Email` then by `Time`**
[image]

[image]  [image]

**Sort by `Test` order and `Time`**
[image]

**`Test` (asc.) then by `Time` (asc.)**
[image]

### Formula Explained

The formula below is the same as above however the `_counters` variable as well as the final `FILTER` function has been broken out into additional steps to make it easier to follow.

```
Line    Formula
----+------------------------------------------
 1  | =LET(
 2  |   _arr, A2:B10,
 3  |   _seq, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_arr)/2),_arr),
 4  |   _sort, SORTBY(_seq,INDEX(_seq,,2),1,INDEX(_seq,,3),1),
 5  |   _names, INDEX(_sort,,2),
 6  |   _counters, MAP(UNIQUE(_names), LAMBDA(u,
 7  |       TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(_names,_names=u)))))),
 8  |   _joined, TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,_counters),
 9  |   _split, TEXTSPLIT(_joined,,","),
10  |   _combined, HSTACK(_sort,_split),
11  |   _storedsort, SORTBY(_combined, INDEX(_combined,,1),1),
12  |   _countersonly, FILTER(_storedsort,{0,0,0,1}),
13  |   _countersonly )
```

| Line | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Use Excel's [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function to store calculations, values, and define names inside the formula. |
| 2 | `_arr:` stores the initial `Email` and `Timestamp` data |
| 3 | `_seq:` [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) function is used to get the current order of the data so it can be restored later. [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) function is used to add it to `_arr` as the first column |
| 4 | `_sort:` [SORTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) function allows ordering the data by email using [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to get the 2nd column of `_seq` and then by `Timestamp` again using [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to get the 3rd column of `_seq` |
| 5 | `_names:` Uses [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to get the list of emails from column 2 of `_sort` |
| 6 | `_counters:` [UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) gets a list of unique emails from `_names` and each unique email is passed into the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function using [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) and the LAMBDA function uses `u` as a placeholder for the mapped values in its formula. |
| 7 | `_counters:` (continued) Each time a value is mapped in, `_names` is filtered for that value, and the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) results are counted using [COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) then that count is used to create a [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) of numbers incrementing by 1, from #1 up to the [COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) result. Lastly, [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) combines the sequence of numbers as a single comma separated string to avoid nested array errors. |
| 8 | `_joined:` [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) is again used to combine the individual sequences of numbers into one long comma separated string that includes the complete [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) for all email addresses. |
| 9 | `_split:` [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) takes that long comma-separated string and splits it onto a single column using each comma to determine when to insert a new row. |
| 10 | `_combined:` similar to what was done on line 3, [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) is again used to combine the column `_split` after the columns from `_sort` |
| 11 | `_storedsort:` [SORTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f) enables restoring the original order of our `Email` and `Timestamp` columns using the 1st column of `_combined` which is the [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) created on line 3 |
| 12 | `_countersonly:` A technique employing [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) allows selectively returning columns by using a `0` to skip a column, and a `1` to show a column. As the 4th column is in the correct order vis-a-vis the original sort order of the `Email` and `Timestamp` columns, columns 1-3 can now be discarded (`{0,0,0,1}`) |

**Line 3: `_seq`**
[image]

**Line 4: `_sort`**
[image]

**Line 5: `_names`**
[image]

**Line 6 - 7: `_counters`**
[image]

**Line 8: `_joined`**
[image]

**Line 9: `_split`**
[image]

**Line 10: `_combined`**
[image]

**Line 11: `_storedsort`**
[image]

**Line 12: `_countersonly`**
[image]

**Line 12: `_countersonly` with
sort by `Email` (asc) then `Time` (asc)**
[image]